# Is there a way to find all processes which accessed a linux port?

Tags: linux, port, load-balancer

We are using Octopus Load Balancer for connecting to database from Linux. The Load balancer throws following error. I doubt if it is due to the assigned port being accessed by some other process randomly. Is there any way I can find out which processes accessed the port at what time and see if it correspond to the time error is received in the Octopus Log?

From Octopus Load Balancer log:

```
Thu May 23 03:56:19 2013 - WARNING: connect_server: cannot connect to member <ip_address>: Cannot assign requested address
Tue May 28 23:28:52 2013 - WARNING: connect_server: cannot connect to member <ip_address>: Cannot assign requested address
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux server, you will not have logs which give you that information automatically, but you could set up a program which will do that for you. For example, with the [constat](http://www.mm.kay-mueller.de/constat.html) package you can log days worth of traffic with ipclog, then parse it by day with constat.